# How to create Dictionary of value be type String and Array of any type?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I need to create dictionary that holds key-value pairs where Key of type String and Value of type Array of Struct, and need to subscript to get the count of Value of given Key. Please help me. Here is how i am creating the desired type, is it correct? and i don't know how to access specific value of a given key.

```
  var BypassDictionary = [String: [ByPassList]]()
```

Comment: Kindly read Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary, to get a basic understanding of how Dictionary works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example

```
struct ByPassList {
    var someValue: Int
}

var bypassDictionary = [String: [ByPassList]]()
bypassDictionary["hello"] = [ByPassList(someValue: 1), ByPassList(someValue: 2)]

if let test = bypassDictionary["hello"] {
    print(test[1])
}
```

Note that var name should begin with a lowercase

Comment: what i want is, i have multiple data like your example test and each of the m has Bypasslist, in your case, it is overriding previous data with new .

Comment: example i want : -> bypassDictionary[ID].append(info), so in this case id and info differ from each other.

Comment: So, to append, you just write: if var test = bypassDictionary["hello"] {
    test.append(ByPassList(someValue: 3))
    print(test[2].someValue)
}

Comment: thank you it is working fine, but what if i want to insert new key-value par right before first element in dictionary?

Comment: To insert in first position, replace test.append(ByPassList(someValue: 3)) by test.insert(ByPassList(someValue: 3), at: 0)

Answer (score 3):

```
struct ByPassData
{
    var name: String
    var address: String
}

var bypassDictionary = [String: [ByPassData]]()
bypassDictionary["test"] = [ByPassData.init(name: "John", address: "FL"),ByPassData.init(name: "Joe", address: "CL")]
bypassDictionary["test1"] = [ByPassData.init(name: "John", address: "FL")]


if let getDataForTest = bypassDictionary["test"]  {
    let countForTest = getDataForTest.count
    print(countForTest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Loop-based

```
struct ByPassList {
    var someValue: Int
}
var dic = [String: [ByPassList]]()
dic["values"] = Array(0...100).map({ByPassList(someValue: $0)})
print(dic["values"])
```

Comment: What's with all the hard coded values? Where does 100 come from?

Comment: This is just a concept. You can implement your own values.

Comment: Ok, I removed my down vote since it compiles but I don't really get this answer. Maybe you should improve it by adding a better description of your code than what you currently have.